# Take an input single dimensional array [1,2,3,4] and output the product of the integers excluding the current index [24,12,8,6];

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Guys I need your opinion; I've encountered this earlier during my interview, I just want to confirm I understood the question right and I got the answer correctly. Thank you. Please check the question and my answer below:

Take an input single dimensional array [1,2,3,4] and output the product of the integers excluding the current index [24,12,8,6];

```
//My answer
function calculate(values:Array):Array {
    var resultArray:Array = new Array();
    for(var i:int = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var getVal1:Number = 1;
        for(var k:int = 0; k <= values.length; k++) {
            if(i != k) {
                var getVal2:Number = values[k];
                getVal1 *= getVal2;
            }
        }
        resultArray.push(getVal1);
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused you want to multiply the values of the arrays together?

Comment: Should be moved to [codereview.SE]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested loops seems like a very messy way to go.

Assuming relatively up-to-date browser (IE 8 and below are out) or suitable shim:

```
var resultArray = sourceArray.map(function(val,ind,arr) {
    arr = arr.slice(0); // create copy of array to work on here
    arr.splice(ind,1); // remove current item from array
    return arr.reduce(function(prev,curr) {return prev*curr;},1);
});
```

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
[`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

**EDIT** Here's another way that should be more efficient:

```
var product = sourceArray.reduce(function(prev,curr) {return prev*curr;},1);
var resultArray = sourceArray.map(function(val) {return product/val;});
```

Comment: Just realised what I did wrong with the pre-edit answer, so that should work now. But yeah, the second one precomputes the total product, so it's faster.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution gives the correct answer, but there is a much more efficient method to calculate the new array:

```
function calculate(values:Array):Array {
    var resultArray:Array = new Array();
    var product:int = 1; 

    for(var i:int = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        product *= values[i];
    }

    for(var i:int = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        resultArray.push(product / values[i]);
    }

    return resultArray;
}
```

This solution has `O(n)` execution time, while your code has `O(n²)` execution time.

Answer (score 1):

That should work. You can do it easier and more efficiently by multiplying all items first:

```
function calculate(values) {
  var prod = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) prod *= values[i];
  var result = [];
  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) result.push(prod / values[i]);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that my code below is very easy to read. And has no nested loops, but two consecutives. My answer would be:

```
function calculate(array){
    var total = array.reduce(function(a, b){
        return a * b;
    });

    return array.map(function(element){
        return total / element;
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly the same. He was quicker! haha

Answer (score 0):

Though I like @Kolink's short-and-efficient solution best, here's another way to solve the task - not using division but still being in `O(n)`:

```
function calculate(values) {
    var acc = 1,
        l = values.length,
        result = new Array(l);
    for (var i=0; i<l; i++) {
        result[i] = acc;
        acc *= values[i];
    }
    acc = 1;
    while(i--) {
        result[i] *= acc;
        acc *= values[i]
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or, the same thing but a little obfuscated*:

```
function calculate(values) {
    var acc = 1,
        i = 0,
        l = values.length,
        result = new Array(l);
    if (l)
        result[i] = 1;
    while( ++i < l)
        result[i] = acc *= values[i-1];
    i -= acc = 1;
    while (i--)
        result[i] *= acc *= values[i+1];
    return result;
}
```

<sub>*: I like shorthand operators!</sub>